# ASP.NET what can cause SetActiveView to fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm troubleshooting a problem in a project I have not developed, it is built in regular asp.net and I have no previous experience of it.

The view has a link that triggers gridViewDevices_RowCommand to change the view. This is the code for the method:

```
protected void gridViewDevices_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    string uuid = gridViewDevices.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value.ToString();
    Device dev = DataHandler.GetDevices().Find(d => d.uuid == uuid);

    UpdateDetailControls(dev);

    Session["editDevice"] = uuid;
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(viewDetails);

}
```

When i click the link the method is triggered, all values are correct and no errors, BUT the view does not change. However when i click it again, the method is triggered again and this time the view changes.

I really can't figure out why it doesnt work the first time, when i step step through the code everything looks correct.

Any ideas how i can solve this?

Comment: Maybe during the same postback you are accidentaly setting another view also as active?

Comment: Almost certainly something is overriding the state of the MultiView. Do you happen to have a PreRender event with something along the lines of if(!IsPostBack) in it or something that touches the MultiView?